# How to loop cut a cylinder properly?

Tags: modeling

I am learning Blender and am doing a tutorial on Youtube by Blender Guru. On this video: [Blender Beginner Tutorial Part 10: Random Colored Sprinkles](https://youtu.be/bLw0HwphXO0) in minute 1:56 he does a perfect loot cut.

However, when I try and repeat the steps I run into an issue. The cylinder deforms on
an inexplicable form.

[image: Picture of deformed solid]

If anyone could provided any help that would be great!

Picture of Blender before and after cutting:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srR64.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NbdL.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had *Auto Merge Vertices* active. Disabling it solved the problem.